# Why is the compiler OK with this?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I spent an embarrassing amount of time last night tracking down a segfault in my application. Ultimately, it turned out I'd written:

```
ANNE_SPRITE_FRAME *desiredFrame;
*desiredFrame = anne_sprite_copy_frame(&sprite->current);
```

instead of:

```
ANNE_SPRITE_FRAME desiredFrame;
desiredFrame = anne_sprite_copy_frame(&sprite->current);
```

In line 1 I created a typed pointer, and in line 2 I set the value of the dereferenced pointer to the struct returned by `anne_sprite_copy_frame()`.

Why was this a problem? And why did the compiler accept this at all? All I can figure is that the problem in example 1 is either:

1. I'm reserving space for the pointer but not the contents that it points to, or
2. (unlikely) it's trying to store the return value in the memory of the pointer itself

Comment: The problems that could arise are all about what would happen at run-time, not compilation, and thus are not the responsibility of the compiler

Comment: Depending on the "real code" this might not help, but, look for "uninitialized variable" warnings in your compiler.  In gcc you need both `-Wuninitialized` and some level of optimization to get such warnings.

Comment: Aha, I'd love getting warnings about stuff like this. Thanks so much. Valgrind complained about uninitialized variables as well, which is actually how I ended up fixing the problem... and thanks to everyone here, I know why it happened and how to not do it again. Score.

Comment: In spite of the comments and answers saying the compiler is not responsible for finding these problems, it is. The C standard does not require it, but a good compiler goes beyond the C standard. A good compiler **should** diagnose an obvious use of an uninitialized object. (`desiredFrame` is uninitialized if it is declared as you show inside a block, not at file scope, and `*desiredFrame` is then a use of an uninitialized object.) As @torek notes, you might not have warnings enabled. You should enable them.

Comment: I don't believe that it IS compatible with both - note that in example 1 I'm assigning it to a variable of type `ANNE_SPRITE_FRAME`, and in example 2 I'm assigning it to a *dereferenced* pointer to `ANNE_SPRITE_FRAME`... which means it's not of pointer type, even though as we've established it doesn't point anywhere.

Comment: Right - it's the left-hand side that was overflowing, that we're concerned with.

Comment: `anne_sprite_copy_frame` has a return type of `ANNE_SPRITE_FRAME`. I believe that the left-hand types are the same - in the first example, the left-hand value is a dereferenced (uninitialized) pointer to `ANNE_SPRITE_FRAME` rather than an `ANNE_SPRITE_FRAME`. They're both the same type, but in the first example the space the variable occupies is not reserved - see H2C03's answer.

Comment: @sudowned: Oops, my mistake, I was thinking of the different left-hand sides with the same declaration of the identifier. Never mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm reserving space for the pointer but not the contents that it points to

Yeah, exactly. But the compiler (unless it does some static analysis) can't infer that. It only sees that the syntax is valid and the types match, so it compiles your program. Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior, though, so your program will most likely work erroneously.

Answer (score 5):

> In line 1 I've created a typed pointer, and in line 2 I set the value of the dereferenced pointer to the struct returned by anne_sprite_copy_frame().

Both of these are allowed in C, which is why this is perfectly acceptable by the compiler.

The compiler doesn't check to make sure your pointer actually points to anything meaningful - it just dereferences and assigns.

One of the best and worst features of C is that the compiler does very little sanity checking for you - it follows your instructions, and does exactly what you tell it to do.  You told it to do two legal operations - even though the variables were not initialized properly.  As such, you get runtime issues, not compile time problems.

Comment: It's a little disconcerting what the compiler will and will not catch. I'm probably leaning on GCC/Clang's warnings a little too hard in terms of telling me when I'm screwing up, but most of the time it'll tell me before I do anything particularly senseless.

Comment: @sudowned In general, C is *very* forgiving of problems.  Errors are rare, and even the warnings won't warn you of many real problems.

Comment: “Allowed in C” does not imply “perfectly acceptable by the compiler”. Good-quality modern compilers are capable of catching many bugs that are permitted by the C standard. In fact, in C 2011, the former code has undefined behavior by C 2011 (N1570) 6.3.2.1 2, which says that using an lvalue of automatic storage duration that never had its address taken is undefined behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes - The C standard does permit it, though - many compilers may provide warnings, but not all do.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Not like the compiler should error out when it encounters some random code invoking UB. Undefined behavior may not even be detectable at compilation time (buffer overruns caused by user input, etc.), but I'm sure you are aware of that. Again, a compiler without any static analysis can be perfectly conformant without issuing a diagnostic about these types of semantic errors.

Answer (score 3):

The pointer is uninitialized, but it still has a value so it points *somewhere*. Writing the return value to that memory address overwrites whatever happens to be there, invoking undefined behavior.

Technically the compiler is not in the business of telling you that a syntactically valid construct will result in undefined (or even likely unexpected) behavior, but I would be surprised if there was no warning issued about this particular usage.

Comment: Hm, I've initialized pointers elsewhere with TYPE *Pointername = NULL; in `main()` with good results. Is this because I'm setting the pointer to point nowhere and subsequently storing something there is assigning it somewhere to point, or is it because the rules in `main()` are different, similar to how uninitialized variables are zeroed out except in functions?

Comment: In C 1999, the uninitialized pointer had an unspecified value, so, in some sense, it pointed “somewhere”, although not necessarily somewhere usable. In C 2011, the uninitialized pointer no longer has an unspecified value; merely using the pointer (e.g., printing its value) is undefined behavior, per C 2011 (N1570) 6.3.2.1 2.

Comment: @sudowned: A pointer always points somewhere, exactly like an integer always has some value -- even though when it's uninitialized you do not know what that value is. The rules are the same in all contexts (`main` is not special), but I 'm not sure what you are doing with the null pointers. Dereferencing them is undefined behavior and typically results in an immediate crash.

Comment: @Jon: As with pointers, it is no longer true (in C 2011) that an integer always has some value. The behavior of using an uninitialized object with automatic storage duration that never had its address taken is undefined. (Formerly, the object had an unspecified value.) Thus, the statements `int x; x;` are permitted by the C standard to cause any behavior whatsoever, even though the expression statement does not do anything with the value of `x`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I suppose so -- I have had zero exposure to C2011, so thanks for filling in these gaps.

Answer (score 1):

C is weakly typed. You can assign anything to anything with the obvious consequences. You have to be very careful and disciplined if you do not want to spend nights uncovering bugs that turn out "stupid". I mean no offense. I went through the same issues due to an array bound overflow that overwrote other variables and only showed up in some other part of the code trying to use these variables. Nightmare! That's why Java is so much easier to deal with. With C you are an acrobat without a net, with Java, you can afford to fall. That said, I do not mean to say Java is better. C has its raison d'etre.

Comment: You're right on all counts, of course, but I'm enjoying working without a net even though, to be perfectly frank, I'm not any good at it yet. :)

Comment: Sure the thrill (if I may say so) is enjoyable indeed. Eventually,  what really counts is what tool does the job best. If you have need to do some low level job then C might be best, for RAD, some other language will certainly be more appropriate. So, again, there is no "best" language per se. Happy programming :-)

Comment: I've had a lot of situations where I've wished I knew C, and I'd like to be a better programmer than ignorance of the fundamentals will allow. For this reason, I'm doing a couple of personal projects in C instead of Java or Ruby in order to get these fundamentals through my head.